# Appending a list to a dataframe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add a list as the 3rd column in a dataframe in a simple program, but keep getting the error

> RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and
> 'int', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects   result =
> result.union(other)

Basically the program should look through the data and find matches of names, then add those along with their time value to a new data set. But I can't get anything to add onto the dataframe after the if statement. The dataframe already has 2 columns that use strings (the 'Name' and 'Time' column) and nothing uses ints so it doesn't make sense why this error comes up. The only thing I've been successful in getting to append is the "matches" which is already in the dataframe. But that is a list just like "test1".

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

```
import os
import csv
import fileinput
import codecs
import pandas as pd
import os
os.chdir('/home/richardwiggles/Desktop')

df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv', names=['Place','Name','Time','City','State','Age'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv', names=['Name','Time'])
test1 = ['a','b','c']

matchesDF = pd.DataFrame()
matches = []

for finishers in df1['Name']:
    matches.append(df2[df2['Name'].str.match(finishers)])

matchesDF=matchesDF.append(matches, ignore_index=True)
matchesDF=matchesDF.append(test1, ignore_index=True)
matchesDF.to_csv(r'/home/richardwiggles/Desktop/data1.csv')
```

The df1 in excel looks like this:

| Place | Name | City | State | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | city1 | state1 | 2:39:06 |
| 2 | name2 | city2 | state2 | 2:39:46 |
| 3 | name3 | city3 | state3 | 2:40:25 |
| 4 | name4 | city4 | state4 | 2:41:44 |
| 5 | name5 | city5 | state5 | 2:45:07 |

df2 in excel looks like this

| Name | Finish |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | 2:31:20 |
| name2 | 2:33:14 |
| name3 | 2:34:44 |
| name4 | 2:35:39 |
| name5 | 2:36:00 |

Comment: Can you provide a sample of both `df1` and `df2`?

Comment: Hah good idea. That is added now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created dummy dataframes and worked with your code, its working for me, with different names etc. Without knowing your dataframe, exact issue can not be deciphered. However, try using **astype(str)** before  .str.match .

```
import os
import csv
import fileinput
import codecs
import pandas as pd
import os

data = {'Place':['EU', 'can', 'in', 'brz'],
        'Name':['alex', 'tom', 'ken', 'keth'],
        'Time': ['20:30','10:45','5:15','2:10'],
        'City' : ['alt','rtx','fgd','hgf'],
        'State' : ['az', 'kz','bz', 'cz'],
        'Age' : [20,30,40,50]}

data2 = {'Name' : ['alex','keth',' '],
         'Time' : ['10:10','7:05','5:15']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

test1 = ['a','b','c']

matchesDF = pd.DataFrame()
matches = []

for finishers in df1['Name']:
    matches.append(df2[df2['Name'].astype(str).str.match(finishers)])

matchesDF=matchesDF.append(matches, ignore_index=True)
matchesDF=matchesDF.append(test1, ignore_index=True)


matchesDF

output:
    Name    Time    0
    0   alex    10:10   NaN
    1   keth    7:05    NaN
    2   NaN NaN a
    3   NaN NaN b
    4   NaN NaN c
```

br,
Simanti.

Comment: I think you're right it could be something with importing the dataframe from excel or something with the format of the dataframe, I hadn't thought to check that. I'll definitely try the astype(str) trick.

Comment: dataframe examples are added now